# The following classes could not be found: - android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android

El error completo es este:

> The following classes could not be found:
>           - android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path,
>   Edit XML, Create Class)

Estoy intentado solucionar este error sin éxito, alguien sabe como solucionarlo? He probado a cambiar algunas versiones de los implementation como he leido en otras preguntar pero no hay manera.

Mi build.gradle es:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gorpe.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    }
```

Edito con el xml donde me esta saltando el error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/link"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="@string/prueba"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView3"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat con los errores que me da

```
2019-09-10 17:41:40.646 5353-5353/com.gorpe.pdf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gorpe.pdf, PID: 5353
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gorpe.pdf/com.gorpe.pdf.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gorpe.pdf-3eKYu64VAEP50O2BSDj2-g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gorpe.pdf-3eKYu64VAEP50O2BSDj2-g==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.gorpe.pdf-3eKYu64VAEP50O2BSDj2-g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.gorpe.pdf.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Gracias y un saludo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir el XML del que se esta quejando y el stack de error completo?

Comment: @solamente he añadido el xml,  que es el stack?

Comment: Cuando digo stackerror me refiero al error que te aparece en logcat completo no unicamente la primera linea. Como dicen en una respuesta espero que haya hecho lo basico clean project / clean sin cache. El xml es correcto.

Comment: @solamente Si lo de hacer clean de proyecto ya lo había probado sin exito, he añadido el logcat completo en el mensaje inicial

Comment: Sigo sin ver el error :/ parece estar bien. El código no lo veo pero a menos que hayas hecho un inflate con una clase distinta al ConstraintLayout no debería darte error. Si tienes el código en github comparte el enlace para poder probarlo en mi máquina y poder trastear un poco a ver si lo saco.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad @Gorpe ¿Cuando creaste el proyecto estaba seleccionada la opción `Use androidx.* artifacts` ?

Comment: @A.Palacio si, estaba seleccionada. No debería haberla marcado?

Comment: @solamente he subido el proyecto al github os dejo el link: https://github.com/Gorpe808/PDF

Comment: @Gorpe lo que debes hacer el modificar el archivo `gradle.properties` y colocarle la almohadilla a `# android.useAndroidX=true` y `# android.enableJetifier=true` despues en tu `Activity` eliminar los imports `import androidx.` e  importalos de nuevo. El unico que debes de eliminar e importar otra vez es: `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado bastante lio con las dependencias de gradle y las versiones usadas, he conseguido que compile y se ejecute sin problemas aqui te dejo el pull request. Espero que con esto puedas continuar.

```
https://github.com/Gorpe808/PDF/pull/1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada para eso estamos :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que el error indica:

> The following classes could not be found: -
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout
>   library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create
>   Class)

Me parece que el problema es simplemente "desincronización", Primeramente asegura tener la dependencia necesaria definida en tu `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}
```

y lo cual al parecer así es, y posteriormente limpia tu proyecto y vuelve a compilar la app:

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra causa de este problema es que tal vez no tengas instalado "ConstraintLayout for Android" , para instalarlo ve a:

`Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Android SDK` > `SDK Tools`

instala:

```
- ConstraintLayout for Android

- Solver for ConstrainLayout
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He probado pero no ha habido éxito

Comment: @Gorpe ok revisa si tienes instalado "ConstraintLayout for Android". Revisa la actualización de mi respuesta.

Comment: no me aparece Support Repository en SDK Tools (uso android studio 3.5)

Comment: @Gorpe el Support Repository es esencial!!! nunca habías realizado un proyecto, revisaste en "SDK Tool"?

Comment: He añadido una captura con las opciones que me salen en el SDK tools